# How to handle HttpClientException properly

Tags: java, spring, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have a webservice which gets data from other webservice and return back to the browser.

1. I want to hide internal client errors
2. Want to throw 404, 400 etc which
   are returned from the webservice in the below method.

How to resolve this problem in a neat way?

Option 1 or Option 2 is clean way?

Option 1

```
public <T> Optional<T> get(String url, Class<T> responseType) {
        String fullUrl = url;
        LOG.info("Retrieving data from url: "+fullUrl);
        try {
            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.setAccept(ImmutableList.of(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
            headers.add("Authorization", "Basic " + httpAuthCredentials);

            HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<>(headers);
            ResponseEntity<T> exchange = restTemplate.exchange(fullUrl, HttpMethod.GET, request, responseType);
            if(exchange !=null)
                return Optional.of(exchange.getBody());
        } catch (HttpClientErrorException e) {
            LOG.error("Client Exception ", e);
            throw new HttpClientError("Client Exception: "+e.getStatusCode());
        }
         return Optional.empty();
  }
```

(or)

Option 2

```
public   <T> Optional<T> get(String url, Class<T> responseType) {
        String fullUrl = url;
        LOG.info("Retrieving data from url: "+fullUrl);
        try {
            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.setAccept(ImmutableList.of(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
            headers.add("Authorization", "Basic " + httpAuthCredentials);

            HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<>(headers);
            ResponseEntity<T> exchange = restTemplate.exchange(fullUrl, HttpMethod.GET, request, responseType);
            if(exchange !=null)
                return Optional.of(exchange.getBody());
            throw new RestClientResponseException("", 400, "", null, null, null);
        } catch (HttpStatusCodeException e) {
            LOG.error("HttpStatusCodeException ", e);
            throw new RestClientResponseException(e.getMessage(), e.getStatusCode().value(), e.getStatusText(), e.getResponseHeaders(), e.getResponseBodyAsByteArray(), Charset.defaultCharset());
        }
        return Optional.empty();
    }
```

Comment: What's the issue with the code above? You use the status code from the internal exception and put it into a new exception, hiding the internal one.

Comment: Option2 looks ugly...Option1 is much better. But i would suggest you to segregate error handler. Create a interceptor which implements "ResponseErrorHandler" provided by spring there you can handle all the error messages so that your code will be much cleaner and you don't require to use try,catch block

Comment: can you point me to a proper example? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have written a sample ResponseErrorHandler for you,

```
public class RestTemplateClientErrorHandler implements ResponseErrorHandler {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RestTemplateClientErrorHandler.class);

@Override
public boolean hasError(ClientHttpResponse clientHttpResponse) throws IOException {
    return RestUtil.isError(clientHttpResponse.getStatusCode());
}

@Override
public void handleError(ClientHttpResponse clientHttpResponse) throws IOException {
    String responseBody = "";
    if(clientHttpResponse != null && clientHttpResponse.getBody() != null){
        responseBody = IOUtils.toString(clientHttpResponse.getBody());
    }
    switch(clientHttpResponse.getRawStatusCode()){
        case 404:
            logger.error("Entity not found. Message: {}. Status: {} ",responseBody,clientHttpResponse.getStatusCode());
            throw new RestClientResponseException(responseBody);
        case 400:
            logger.error("Bad request for entity. Message: {}. Status: {}",responseBody, clientHttpResponse.getStatusCode());
            throw new RestClientResponseException(StringUtils.EMPTY, 400,StringUtils.EMPTY, StringUtils.EMPTY, StringUtils.EMPTY, StringUtils.EMPTY);
        default:
            logger.error("Unexpected HTTP status: {} received when trying to delete entity in device repository.", clientHttpResponse.getStatusCode());
            throw new RestClientResponseException(responseBody);
    }

}

public static class RestUtil {

    private RestUtil() {
        throw new IllegalAccessError("Utility class");
    }

    public static boolean isError(HttpStatus status) {
        HttpStatus.Series series = status.series();
        return HttpStatus.Series.CLIENT_ERROR.equals(series)
                || HttpStatus.Series.SERVER_ERROR.equals(series);
    }
}
}
```

Note : This is common ResponseErrorHandler for your restTemplate and it will catch all the exceptions thrown by restTemplate you don't require try,catch block in each method and you don't need to catch "HttpStatusCodeException" or any other exception.

Please use the below code to register this ErrorHandler.

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
restTemplate.setErrorHandler(new RestTemplateClientErrorHandler());
```

You can also find examples [here](http://www.javased.com/?api=org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler).

You can refactor your client class like this,

```
public <T> Optional<T> get(String url, Class<T> responseType) {
    String fullUrl = url;
    LOG.info("Retrieving data from url: "+fullUrl);
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();

       headers.setAccept(ImmutableList.of(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
        headers.add("Authorization", "Basic " + httpAuthCredentials);

        HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<>(headers);
        ResponseEntity<T> exchange = restTemplate.exchange(fullUrl, HttpMethod.GET, request, responseType);
        if(exchange !=null)
            return Optional.of(exchange.getBody());
     return Optional.empty();
}
```

So your method not looking beautiful now ? Suggestions welcome.

Comment: Can you remove the down vote for this question. I guess, the question is quite reasonable. And yes in the beginning, I was not very clear about what I was looking for. Sorry

Comment: @MinishaMurugan I didn't downvote the question it was somebody who did it. But that doesn't matter you got the answer right ...so no worries enjoy pannuga